# is it possible to hide packages on launchpad.net?

Tags: software-installation, launchpad

so I'm was looking at PPA for the paper theme (click [here](https://launchpad.net/%7Esnwh/+archive/ubuntu/pulp))

and it doesn't list the cursor theme. It only shows the icon and the GTK theme. I've looked at the build logs and I cannot find it.

but I can install it after adding the PPA.

apt install paper-cursor-theme

Not really sure if this is an Ubuntu question but definitely Ubuntu related since this website is frequently used.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://launchpad.net/~snwh/+archive/ubuntu/pulp/+packages

The cursors are part of the icon theme and you can also download the DEB for the cursors itself here:

[image]